# Linkify annuls my TextView text alignment

Tags: android, textview, text-alignment, linkify

I am using this piece of code to make my textView justified.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
   textView.justificationMode = LineBreaker.JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD
} else {
   textView.gravity = Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL
}
```

But when I use `textView.autoLinkMask = Linkify.WEB_URLS` the text alignment of my textView gets annulled. Respectively the text alignment is annulled only if there is some clickable URL. If the textView doesn't contain any URL, the text alignment remains justified.

I tried some libraries (e.g., BetterLinkMovementMethod), but also without success.

Any help? Or is this a standard behavior, and the text alignment of linkified text can't be changed?